# API credentials as federated aws user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

my company provides me with a federated access to AWS. By that I mean, we're going to a website where we login with our SSO which then allows us to pull up the AWS console (i.e. through as custom federation broker as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-custom-url.html) 
I can create instances (ec2) just fine through the UI. My question is, how can I get API credentials to use with aws cli? 
In the IAM dashboard I don't see an option to create a credential set for myself.

Is this even something I can get to, or do they (=my it people) need to change something in the setup?

Thanks a bunch!

ps. to clarify, this we're not going through onelogin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a program to do this leveraging your credentials, your SSO config, and boto3.

Alternatively, I use this google chrome plugin: https://github.com/prolane/samltoawsstskeys/blob/master/README.md

Atlassian also released a tool recently to help solve this problem, and there are some other ones out there if you do some searching.